# Is using an IMU suitable for measuring the vibrations of the string?

Tags: waves, string, vibrations

I want to measure the vibrations of the guitar string. I've got an IMU sensor. I want to mount it on a string and measure the vibrations of the element. 
IMU: Sparkfun ITG3200
I'm not pretty sure is it suitable for my purpose, because I didn't find much about this method on the Web. Is it gonna work? Or maybe, is there a another method for doing it but with the mentioned IMU?

Comment: Expand acronyms: IMU = Inertial Measurement Unit